# How to generates a plot of f as a function of x from dynamic xmin to dynamics xmax?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Good day! I want that with the following code it is possible to enter the minimum and maximum range of the variables x and y, but when running it the following error appears:

> Limiting value uMin in {x,uMin,uMax} is not a machine-sized real \
>   number.

```
Panel[Manipulate[tick; Dynamic[b = 8]; Dynamic[c = 4]; 
Dynamic[uMin = -5]; Dynamic[uMax = 5]; 
KFigE = Dynamic[
Plot3D[dydx /. {B -> b, C -> c}, {x, uMin, uMax}, {y, uMin, 
  uMax}]],
Grid[{
{Style["PLOT", "Title"], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
{Style["Start:", Blue, Bold, 15]},
{Style["Initial Conditions", Blue, Bold, 15]},
{Style["b", Bold, 12], 
 InputField[Dynamic[b], Number, Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.7], 
  ImageSize -> 80],
 Style["uMin", Bold, 12], 
 InputField[Dynamic[uMin], Number, 
  Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.7], ImageSize -> 80]},
{Style["c", Bold, 12], 
 InputField[Dynamic[c], Number, Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.7], 
  ImageSize -> 80],
 Style["uMax", Bold, 12], 
 InputField[Dynamic[uMax], Number, 
  Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.7], ImageSize -> 80]},
{Button["Do it", tick = Not[tick], 
  Background -> Lighter[Green, 0.5], ImageSize -> {80, 40}],
 Button["Clear", {dydx = Null, b = Null, c = Null}, 
  Background -> LightRed, ImageSize -> {80, 40}],
 Button["Export", 
  Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "untitled"], KFigE], 
  Background -> LightBlue, ImageSize -> {80, 40}, 
  Method -> "Queued"]}}, Spacings -> {2, 1}],
  {{dydx, 3*(B*x + C*y), "Equation", None}, 
  Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.7], ImageSize -> 200},
  {{tick, False}, None}, TrackedSymbols :> {tick}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left]]
```

It only works when the values of `uMin` and `uMax` have been previously loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate) seems very complicated, with unnecessary [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic) wrappers all over the place. Here's a stripped down version that replicates your issue:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot3D[dydx /. {B->b,C->c},{x,uMin,uMax},{y,uMin,uMax}],
    Grid[{
        {Control@{{b,Null},InputField[#, Number]&},Control@{{uMin,Null},InputField[#,Number]&}},
        {Control@{{c,Null},InputField[#,Number]&},Control@{{uMax,Null},InputField[#,Number]&}}
    }],
    {{dydx,3 (B x + C y), "Equation", None}},
    ControlPlacement -> Left
]
```

Since the [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D) is complaining about `uMin` and `uMax` not being numeric, you can wrap the plot in an [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If) statement. The following works fine:

```
Manipulate[
    If[AllTrue[{uMin, uMax}, NumericQ],
        Plot3D[dydx /. {B->b,C->c},{x,uMin,uMax},{y,uMin,uMax}],
        Graphics[{}]
    ],
    Grid[{
        {Control@{{b,Null},InputField[#, Number]&},Control@{{uMin,Null},InputField[#,Number]&}},
        {Control@{{c,Null},InputField[#,Number]&},Control@{{uMax,Null},InputField[#,Number]&}}
    }],
    {{dydx,3 (B x + C y), "Equation", None}},
    ControlPlacement -> Left
]
```

Comment: Works correctly! The best ideas are the simplest.